# MongoDB- Subtract

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Basically I want to subtract finish-start for each object.
So in the below example, the output should be 2 and 4 ((7-5=2) and (8-4=4)) and then I want to add that both fields into my existing documents.

How can I do this in MongoDB?

```
{   
    "title" : "The Hobbit",
    "rating_average" : "???",
    "ratings" : [
        {
            "title" : "best book ever",
            "start" : 5,
            "finish" : 7
        },
        {
            "title" : "good book",
            "start" : 4,
            "finish" : 8
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly are the requirements for query output but this might help..

**Query:**

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$ratings" },
    { $addFields: { "ratings.diff": { $subtract: [ "$ratings.finish", "$ratings.start" ] } } }
])
```

**Pipeline Explanation:**

1. Unwind the array because the $subtract cannot act on array data.
2. Add a new field called diff in the 'ratings' sub documents that has
   the calculated value

**EDIT:**

OP asks for the results to be stored in the same subdocument.  After discussions with friends and family I discovered this is possible but only with MongoDB version 4.2 or later.  Here is an update statement that can achieve the desired results.  This is an update not an aggregation.

**Update:** (MongoDB 4.2 or later specific)

```
db.books.update({
},
[
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      ratings: {
        $map: {
          input: "$ratings",
          in: {
            start: "$$this.start",
            finish: "$$this.finish",
            diff: {
              $subtract: [
                "$$this.finish",
                "$$this.start"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: This looks fine but How do I save this into my documents?(update this with in my existing document

Comment: @user12487929 - just for clarification, you want to calculate a value from two fields in a document, then update the document to include this calculated value?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate(subtract) a value from two fields in a document, then update the document to include this calculated value.

Comment: Were you able to find any solutions?

Comment: @user12487929 - I am still doing research.  This basic use case seems difficult to solve.

Comment: @user12487929 - I am trying to determine if there is a way to do this set-based.  Most 'quick' answers simply say query the data, and for each document found do an update statement.  Updating every found document is a lot of churn for a simple use case, and the answer feels like a punt .

Comment: Yes it looks like a simple use case, but has a limited resource on it. Let me know if you find any solution for this.

Comment: @user12487929 - basic does not imply simple.  Basic merely implies common.  I would have expected Mongo to address this a long time ago.  As it turns out the ability to do what you are asking has only recently become available.  Crazy.